# How to automatically update cells range in Excel depends on value of given cell?

Tags: excel-2010

In *Excel 2010* I need to *calculate sum of cells in column*. *Starting* row number is always the same however *ending* row depends on value given in other cell. Let's assume that I want to calculate sum of cells

`A1:A(1+X)` where `X` is a value of cell named `X`. If `X=2` than range for calculation will be `A1:A3`, `if X=4` than range for calculation will be `A1:A5` and so on. Of course `X` is a name of cell, not its address. With changes of X value range of calculation will change as well. I tried to use addressing like `A1:A(1+X)` but it doesn't work.

Anybody has idea if it's possible to use this kind of addressing and how?

Answer (score 0):

You want the [Indirect](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-HP005209139.aspx) function. Pass it a string containing a cell reference, and it'll work as if you referenced the cell directly. To have a range, put the call to Indirect before or after the `:` that defines the range: For example: `A1:INDIRECT(...)`.

Here's my test spreadsheet:

```
 | A  | B
-+----+-----------------------------
1| 11 | Sum this many cells
2| 22 | 2
3| 33 | Here's the sum:
4| 44 | =SUM(A1:INDIRECT(("A"&B2)))
5| 55 |
```

In cell B4, I create a range by specifying the beginning of the range (`A1`) and use Indirect for the end of the range. I use a hard-coded "A", and concatenate that with the integer value from another cell, and pass the result of the concatenation ("A2") to Indirect.